# Multiple aframe animations

Tags: aframe

I have built a scripted animation from point A to B to C and so on.

Animations are triggered via JS (e.g document.getElementById('camera').emit('animazione_zero_avanti')).

I am creating animations like this:

i would like to add a Z-Axis rotation as well to the first animation.
Can an animation have multiple attributes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some more code? What you defined animations look like and what you have so far?

Comment: my bad: this went lost somewhere:

<a-animation id="zero_avanti" attribute="position" begin="animazione_zero_avanti" from="0 0 15" to="0 0 9"> </a-animation>

Comment: Can you re-clarify the question? Do you want an animation with multiple attributes, or are you asking about rotating the camera?

Comment: The animation now changes the camera position.
I would like, on same animation, to both slide the camera AND rotate it around Z-Axis (so that the ground plane gets slightly tilted too). I hope this helps.

Comment: You can add multiple `<a-animation>` elements.

Though note that rotating the camera or taking control of it is heavily not recommended for VR due to sickness. And you might have troubles since the controls continuously update the camera.

You might be able to animate a wrapper entity, but then the rotations will compose weirdly.

Comment: could you please make a practical example? :)

Answer (score 2):

> You can add multiple  elements. Though note that rotating the camera or taking control of it is heavily not recommended for VR due to sickness. And you might have troubles since the controls continuously update the camera. You might be able to animate a wrapper entity, but then the rotations will compose weirdly.

```
<a-camera>
  <a-animation attribute="position" ...></a-animation>
  <a-animation attribute="rotation" ...></a-animation>
</a-camera>
```

Or

```
<a-entity>
  <a-animation attribute="rotation" ...></a-animation>
  <a-camera>
    <a-animation attribute="position" ...></a-animation>
  </a-camera> 
</a-entity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from `aframe` version 0.9.0 `<a-animation>` is no longer supported.

But you can still use and combine animations using the property `animation`.

For example:

```
<a-sphere color="blue" radius="0.5" position="0 0.5 0" segments-height="53"
    animation='   property: position; dur: 5000; from: -2 0.5 0; to: 2 0.5 0; dir: alternate; easing: linear; loop: true;'
    animation__2='property: rotation; dur: 1000; from: 0 0 0;    to: 0 360 0; dir: normal;    easing: linear; loop: true;'
    animation__3='property:    scale; dur: 1000; from: 1 1 1;    to: 2 2 2;   dir: alternate; easing: linear; loop: true;'>
</a-sphere>
```

A live example can be found at this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/derzu/pen/wvMOKav).

More detail at the `a-frame` [API](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/animation.html).