# <a-animation> not working in aframe 0.9.2

Tags: javascript, aframe

I try to change the radius of a nested child element with animation. My code looks like this:

```html
<a-sphere id="outer-sphere" radius="0.6" material="color:white;opacity: 0.6">
    <a-sphere id="inner-sphere" radius="0.1" material="color:red; opacity: 0.6">
        <a-animation property="radius" from="0.1" to="0.6" begin="fillSphere"></a-animation>
    </a-sphere>
</a-sphere>
```

in my react code I catch the mouseOver event from the parent

```js
const onMouseEnter = (e) => {
   const innerSphere = e.target.querySelector('#inner-sphere');
   innerSphere.emit("fillSphere");
}
```

but nothing happens. Or is there another way to animate a child entity. For example with the Aframe animation attribute. I could not find anything in the A-Frame documentation.

I use A-Frame in Version 0.9.2

Comment: If you change the title to **<a-animation> not working in aframe 0.9.2** it will be more helpful for others with similar problems :)

Comment: I changed the title ;)

Comment: feel free to mark the anwser if its working for you. Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<a-animation>` element was deprecated in `a-frame 0.9.0` in favor of the [animation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/animation.html#sidebar) component.

It should look a little bit like this:

```
<a-sphere id="outer-sphere" radius="0.6" material="color:white;opacity: 0.6">
    <a-sphere id="inner-sphere" radius="0.1" material="color:red; opacity: 0.6"
              animation="property: radius; from: 0.1; to: 0.6: startEvents: fillSphere">
    </a-sphere>
</a-sphere>
```

Comment: For multiple animations see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63078982/1178478